# Bind DataGrid to ListBox selected item

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

In my application I have a `ListBox` that is bound to an `ObservableCollection` in my ViewModel. In the same window I have a `DataGrid`. I want that `DataGrid` to display the currently selected item from the `ListBox` - which means one item from the `ObservableCollection`. How can it be done (How should my `DataGrid` be written)?

My `ListBox`:

```
<ListBox x:Name="listBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,36.667" Width="119" ItemsSource="{Binding ReportItems}" >
```

**EDIT:**

I think that my question is not clear enough.

I want the `DataGrid` to display an item from an `ObservableCollection` that the user selects in the `ListBox`.

My ViewModel:

```
public class MainViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<ReportItem> ReportItems { get; set; }
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        ReportItems = new ObservableCollection<ReportItem>();
        ReportItems.Add(Example);
    }
    public ReportItem Example = new TextReportItem() { Name = "aviran", DataFile = "aviran.txt"};
}
```

Class `ReportItem`:

```
public class ReportItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string DataFile { get; set; }
}
```

Classes `TextReportItem`, `TextParcel`:

```
 public class TextReportItem : ReportItem
{
    public ObservableCollection<TextParcel> TItems { get; set; }
}
public class TextParcel
{
    char Delimiter { get; set; }
    string LineExp { get; set; }
    string Result { get; set; }
    string IgnoreLine { get; set; }
    int DesiredResultIndexInLine { get; set; }
}
```

My window:

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ReportMaker"
    xmlns:ViewModel="clr-namespace:ReportMaker.ViewModel" x:Class="ReportMaker.MainWindow"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.DataContext>
    <ViewModel:MainViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <Button x:Name="button" Content="Create" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,10,10" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="75"/>
    <ComboBox x:Name="comboBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,0,0,10" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="120"/>
    <ListBox x:Name="listBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,36.667" Width="119" ItemsSource="{Binding ReportItems}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" />
    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="274" Margin="134,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="375" x:Name="selectedItemStackPannel">
        <StackPanel.Resources>
            <Style x:Key="ControlBaseStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Control}">
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0, 10, 0, 0" />
            </Style>
        </StackPanel.Resources>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="Name:"/>
            <TextBox Width="150"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="Data File:"/>
            <TextBox Width="150"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <DataGrid Height="190" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"  x:Name="dataGridForSelectedTextItem"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <Button x:Name="button_Copy" Content="Save" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,92,10" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="75"/>

</Grid>
```

Comment: I do what you try with 2 Datagrids. Select an item in Datagrid and show information about that selected item in the tother datagrid. For this I've bound the `SelectionChanged`-event of the first datagrid to a function where I set the ItemsSource to the current selected Item. Just for the case you wanna try that in code-behind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ListBox` has a `SelectedItems` field as well, just bind to that. Supports multiple and extended selection too!

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=listBox, Path=SelectedItems}" />
```

Comment: Thank you, that answered the question. But I now realized that I only want to display `TItems` property of the selected item in the `DataGrid`. I also have other properties that I want to display in different controls - how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

How about :

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=listBox,Path=SelectedItem}"/DataGrid>
```

Comment: Thank you, but this doesn't work. The DataGrid shows nothing. Maybe it's related to the `ObservableCollection` being inside the ViewModel?

Comment: It might be because your dataGrid is inside a stackpanel - as a test, try putting it on the same level as the listbox. Also, do you see any errors from the output window in VS pertaining to binding errors for your datagrid ?

Comment: I tried to put the `DataGrid` on the same level as the `ListBox`, still doesn't work.. I don't see any errors in the output window. Do I need to set `SelectedItem` in the `ListBox`?

Comment: Yes, i believe you should set the SelectedItem to a property on your VM - when you update the item in your listbox, that property will update. You can actually try binding your datagrid item source to that selected item VM property (but the above XAML should also work).